# Revert back to previous environment in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Some one was working on my system and changed my environment settings. I want to revert back to my environment. I want to work on Java 1.4.
When I check the properties of each project it shows that 1.4 is being used.
And I am not sure what changes were done on my environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse go to the `Window` menu, `Preferences`, `Java`, `Installed JREs` and confirm that you have the version of java checked that you want to use.

I don't know how to determine what was changed as there is no version control system in place for Eclipse.  If you must you can remove the configs or reinstall it from scratch. Granted that is not a fun option but I have had to do that when a plugin messed up Eclipse and I had couldn't undo it.  In the future, you may want to set up Eclipse with what ever plugins and settings that you like and then make a copy and work in the copy. (I actually do this due to the plugin problems I had years ago)

Comment: Thank you. jre6 has been installed. How do I change it to jre4?

Comment: Assuming you have jre4 still installed, from the `Installed JREs` form select the `Add...` button, use the default `Standard VM` and click Next, select the `Directory...` button on the `JRE home:` line.  Then browse to JRE 4.

Comment: how can I revert back to default settings in eclipse?

Comment: Most, if not all, of the settings are in the workspace.  Create a new workspace and import your project into it.